# Pass MySQL datas to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have some MySQL datas in a table. This table shows how the datas are connected to each other. I also have buttons for each datas. And I want to visualize these relations. I'm using vis.js for the visualization. I'm new in Javascript and I don't know how to pass the MySQL datas to the `function drawNetwork()`. How can I do this?

### Example

```js
function drawNetwork() {

  var nodes = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'data1',
      shape: 'box'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'data2',
      shape: 'box'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      label: 'data3',
      shape: 'box'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      label: 'data4',
      shape: 'box'
    }
  ];

  var edges = [{
      from: 1,
      to: 2,
      label: 'Description1',
      arrows: {
        to: true
      }
    },
    {
      from: 1,
      to: 3,
      label: 'Description2',
      font: {
        align: 'top'
      },
      arrows: {
        to: true
      }
    },
    {
      from: 1,
      to: 4,
      label: 'Description3',
      font: {
        align: 'top'
      },
      arrows: {
        to: true
      }
    }
  ];

  var container = document.getElementById('network-container');

  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };

  var width = 600;
  var height = 500;
  var options = {
    width: width + 'px',
    height: height + 'px',
    edges: {
      smooth: false
    },
    physics: false,
    interaction: {
      hover: true,
      dragNodes: true, // allow dragging nodes
      zoomView: false, // do not allow zooming
      dragView: false // do not allow dragging
    }
  };




  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

}

$('#model4temp').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  drawNetwork();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.17.0/vis.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.17.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Connect to</th>
            <th>View</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2, Data3, Data4</td>
            <td><input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#model4temp' value="View" class="btn btn-success btn-md"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3, Data4</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="model4temp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sample Network in modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="network-container" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I'm new in Javascript and I don't know how to pass the MySQL datas to the function drawNetwork(). How can I do this?"  Search Javascript Ajax.

Comment: As Raymond says, you will need to look into AJAX. Make a request to a PHP file that fetches the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your mysql data in this variable "network" then just do this.

```
$('#model4temp').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  drawNetwork(network);
});
```

And define your function like this

```
function drawNetwork(network) {
  // Your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data you need to make a request to the server(a computer that serves data).

How do you do it?

Browser:
Enter resource address to your address bar. When you request a web page the server sends you data.(HTML raw text that is latter rendered to form this web page)

**JavaScript:**

To programmatically do it, you need a set of a protocol.

***Case 1:*** How does the client(Browser) request data?

***Case 2:*** How does the server respond to the request?

- Case 1: Requesting data with JavaScript.

In JavaScript you can use the following code to request data.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", true);
xhttp.send();
```

The url **https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2**
responds with data, your MYSQL data from the server.

But how is it possible?

Well, each server has its own back end mechanism. Let's use php for responding to server requests(GET Requests)

---

- Case 2: Responding Case 1 request with PHP.

---

```
$result = Array( 'Categories' => Array(), 'Products' => Array());

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( 'SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM category' );
$stmt->bind_result( $id, $parent_id, $name );
$stmt->execute();
while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
  $result['Categories'][] = Array( 'id' => $id, 'parent_id' => $parent_id, 'name' => $name );
} 
$stmt->close();
//Do the same for the other one

$jsonstring = json_encode( $result );
```

The    $jsonstring  variable contains the data you need and you can **echo** it to respond to any request.

But how does JavaScript handle responses from the server, so that you use it in your browser?

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  //use data here.(here we just print the data on the screen)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I hope this helps, you can do the same with jquery easily

```
$.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

What you need to research on:
[AJAX Calls in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp),
[working with databases with PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)(or any other language)

This is just a basic intro, you will need to use the keywords in this post to research on what you should know.